# Blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, axios

```
 export const getMovies = (text) => async (dispatch) => {
 
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/4/search/movie?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-us&page=1&include_adult&query=${text}` );
  
    dispatch({
      type: GET_MOVIES,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

I am encountering the following error when I run this line of code in my REACT/REDUX project:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.themoviedb.org/4/search/movie?api_key=b1d71b9e30e9e87132c7a808864f227c&language=en-us&page=1&include_adult&query=' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field auth-token is not 
allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Any input towards solving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of input would you like? It says what the issue is.

Comment: Well obviously I'd like to understand why this is happening and what i need to do to have the API call run successfully.

Comment: your api needs some change so, that it treats this request as it is originating from the same origin. Generally in a sprint boot application there used to an annotation AllwCrossOrigin=* which used to work

Comment: Can you explain that in newbie terms? I don't understand what you're saying I need to do.

Comment: @TNT928 He's saying you need to fix the server side, which isn't relevant here, since AFAICT it's not your server.

Comment: If it helps I can provide a link to the repository. Its https://github.com/TNT928/movierental

Comment: @TNT928 For cors to work from localhost you may need to [set withCredentials flag false](https://www.themoviedb.org/talk/5cd8b7c7c3a3681443bfff4f) [Here](https://flaviocopes.com/axios-credentials/) is how you can do it with acios